# Rust Network Interface

Tags: rust

I have written code related to network communication interface which basically has functionalities of create socket and send & receive data. Currently this supports only IPV4 but facing lot of difficulties when making it to work with both IPV4 and IPV6.

```
use std::net::{UdpSocket, SocketAddrV4, Ipv4Addr};
use std::net::SocketAddr::V4;
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct NetworkInterface {
    socket: Option<UdpSocket>,

    recv_sock_addr: Option<SocketAddrV4>,
    send_sock_addr: Option<SocketAddrV4>,
}

impl NetworkInterface {
    pub fn new() -> NetworkInterface {
        NetworkInterface {
            socket: None,
            recv_sock_addr: None,
            send_sock_addr: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn bind_socket(&mut self, ip_addr: &str, port: u16) {
        let pos = ip_addr.find('.').unwrap();
        let first_octet: u8 = ip_addr[..pos].parse().unwrap();

        if first_octet > 223 && first_octet < 240 {
            self.recv_sock_addr = Some(SocketAddrV4::new(Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED, port));
        } else {
            self.recv_sock_addr = Some(SocketAddrV4::new(Ipv4Addr::from_str(ip_addr).unwrap(), port));
        }

        self.socket = Some(UdpSocket::bind(self.recv_sock_addr.as_ref().unwrap()).unwrap());
        if first_octet > 223 && first_octet < 240 {
            let _ = self.socket.as_ref().unwrap().join_multicast_v4(&Ipv4Addr::from_str(ip_addr).unwrap(), &Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED);
        }
    }

    pub fn set_send_sock_addr(&mut self, ip_addr: &str, port: u16) {
        self.send_sock_addr = Some(SocketAddrV4::new(Ipv4Addr::from_str(ip_addr).unwrap(), port));

        let pos = ip_addr.find('.').unwrap();
        let first_octet: u8 = ip_addr[..pos].parse().unwrap();
        if first_octet > 223 && first_octet < 240 {
            self.socket.as_ref().unwrap().set_multicast_loop_v4(false).expect("set_multicast_loop_v4 call failed");
        }
    }

    pub fn recv_data(&self, buff: &mut[u8]) -> usize {
        let(recvd_bytes_len, _) = self.socket.as_ref().unwrap().recv_from(buff).expect("error while receiving data");

        recvd_bytes_len
    }

    pub fn send_data(&self, buff: &[u8]) {
        self.socket.as_ref().unwrap().send_to(buff, self.send_sock_addr.as_ref().unwrap()).expect("error while sending data");
    }

    pub fn get_host_bound_port(&self) -> u16 {
        self.socket.as_ref().unwrap().local_addr().unwrap().port()
    }

    pub fn update_send_sock_addr(&mut self) {
        let mut buff: [u8; 2048] = [0; 2048];
        let (_, send_sock_addr) = self.socket.as_ref().unwrap().recv_from(&mut buff).expect("error while receiving data during sender IP address updating");

        match send_sock_addr {
            V4(ip_addr) => self.send_sock_addr = Some(ip_addr),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You `.unwrap()` a lot. Consider handling the errors instead of risking panics.

Comment: Also what was your reasoning that let you come up with the magic buffer size of `2048`?

Comment: to be honest no logical reasoning. Do you think I need to keep it 2^16?

Answer (score 3):

Adapting your code to supporting both IpV4 and IpV6 should be straightforward. Just use the `IpAddr` and `SocketAddr` types instead of the `IpV4Addr` and `SocketAddrV4` types.

```
pub fn new() -> NetworkInterface {
pub fn bind_socket(&mut self, ip_addr: &str, port: u16) {
```

Is there a reason to separate `new` from `bind_socket`? It seems that the only practical use would be to call `new()` and then immediately `bind_socket`. But in that case, it would be better to simply have one function which returns a bound `NetworkInterface`. This would simplify your implementation as the `UdpSocket` would not have to be in an `Option`

```
    let pos = ip_addr.find('.').unwrap();
    let first_octet: u8 = ip_addr[..pos].parse().unwrap();
```

You're parsing the first octet out of the ip_address. But you're going to need to parse the ip address anyways, so use that.

```
let address = IpV4Addr::from_str(ip_addr);
let first_octet = address.octets()[0];
```

That way you only parse it once and it's just easier to follow.

```
    if first_octet > 223 && first_octet < 240 {
```

If you parse it as suggested, you can use the `is_multicast` method instead.

```
        self.recv_sock_addr = Some(SocketAddrV4::new(Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED, port));
    } else {
        self.recv_sock_addr = Some(SocketAddrV4::new(Ipv4Addr::from_str(ip_addr).unwrap(), port));
    }


    self.socket = Some(UdpSocket::bind(self.recv_sock_addr.as_ref().unwrap()).unwrap());
```

You don't really need to store the `recv_sock_addr`. You don't use it again after this function, and its available via `self.socket.local_addr()` anyways.

```
    if first_octet > 223 && first_octet < 240 {
        let _ = self.socket.as_ref().unwrap().join_multicast_v4(&Ipv4Addr::from_str(ip_addr).unwrap(), &Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED);
    }
}
```

This code deliberately ignores the result returned from join_multicast. DO NOT DO THIS. DO NOT SILENTLY IGNORE ERRORS. Either return the error, or unwrap it, or at the very least leave it as warning produced by compiler.

```
pub fn set_send_sock_addr(&mut self, ip_addr: &str, port: u16) {
```

`UdpSocket` has a connect method which seems like it might do what you want already.